# Time dilation + length contraction + lack of privileged reference frames

Tags: special-relativity

According to Einstein's postulates for special relativity, the laws of physics are preserved in all reference frames.

So, there exists a reference frame in which the Earth is a spheroid, rather than a sphere. The same would be true for a huge ball of water that ought to readily rearrange itself to minimize gravitational potential. This frame of reference seems to blatantly disregard basic classical physics. So how can all laws be preserved in this case?

There are reference frames in which a particular caesium-133 atom takes much longer than 1 second to achieve 9,192,631,770 transition periods. How can this be reconciled with the claim that this duration is constant, and not just constant, but so static that it can be used to define an SI unit?

If my friend boards a spaceship that leaves earth and eventually reaches speeds that, from the perspective of Earth, approach the speed of light, they will be flattened (given the appropriate angle of exit from earth) to heights of less than 1 nanometer, while retaining their full width and length. Biochemically, how can they survive such a state? All of biochemistry is based on the laws of chemistry and physics, whose laws are supposedly preserved in all reference frames, including that of Earth, so we should be able to conduct a biochemical analysis from any reference frame and expect accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up "the laws of physics" with "observing exactly the same thing". Even if we "see" squished shapes, longer times, etc. the laws of physics are all still the same. There would never be a way to say, "ah yes, I'm in a moving frame". There is no physical way to determine absolute motion; you can only determine relative motion.

Comment: I don't think that sufficiently explains anything. Observing the same thing is trivial in virtue of the fact that we are all living in the same reality. We get that for free. If that was all there was to it, I could define a privileged reference frame by stating that it is the one in which the Earth obeys the obvious laws of classical mechanics. But I obviously cannot, so why is that?

Comment: @HeroicReinforcements But we don't observe exactly the same thing. When I'm driving in my car, I see myself at rest and three trees move by me. Someone standing by a tree will see the trees at rest and myself moving past them. The laws of physics are still the same though, even if we observe things differently.

Comment: " _Earth obeys the obvious laws of classical mechanics_ " The "obvious laws" of classical mechanics were modified and superseded by the laws of Einsteinian mechanics. The equation for Newton's 2nd law is also modified.   The classic Newton's 2nd law is an approximation of the actual law . This approximation works exceedingly well at daily low life speeds. At relativistic speeds, the "obvious" Newton's 2nd law does not work

Comment: @silverhaul Right, I was using it as an example of a law. It wasn't initially clear to me how anything relativistic could cause a mass of water shaped like a spheroid to preserve its shape just because its moving fast

Answer (score 1):

> This frame of reference seems to blatantly disregard basic classical physics. So how can all laws be preserved in this case?

The basic classical physics you refer to is not actually a law of physics. In fact, it is only a decent approximation of the actual laws of physics. This approximation is only valid in the classical domain.

For the spheroidal ball of water for example, the applicable law of physics would be general relativity. You can use general relativity to model the shape of a ball of fluid (e.g. a star) acting under its own gravity and pressure, and you can do so in any reference frame. If you solve those equations in a “classical” frame you get a sphere and if you use the same laws and same fluid and solve them in a relativistic frame then you get the spheroid.

The same laws of physics do apply in both frames, you just have to use the appropriate laws and not non-relativistic approximations.

> How can this be reconciled with the claim that this duration is constant, and not just constant, but so static that it can be used to define an SI unit?

The SI defines the second as a measure of proper time. That is a relativistic invariant.

> Biochemically, how can they survive such a state?

All of the atoms are equally flattened, so the biochemistry works fine. Enzymes that catalyzed a reaction before being flattened continue to catalyze the flattened reaction after being flattened.

Comment: "The SI defines the second as a measure of proper time. That is a relativistic invariant."

Does this mean the caesium-133 atom needs to be stationary to exhibit exactly 9,192,631,770 transitions per second? What accounts for the discrepancy in this rate if it is moving at fast speeds?

Comment: @HeroicReinforcements no, proper time is a relativistic invariant. All frames agree on its value, regardless of the speed. There is no discrepancy to account for. You are thinking of coordinate time, not proper time. The SI second is a unit of proper time, not coordinate time.

Comment: I understand proper time, and how the SI unit can be defined in terms of it. Im phrasing the problem in another context now. As a stationary observer, we would measure a caesium-133 atom inside a train moving at near-speed-of-light, to have less than 9,192,631,770 transitions per second, as a basic consequence of time dilation. How can this discrepancy be explained? Are there other mechanisms in play when an atomic is moving that fast?

Comment: It sounds like you should open a new question where you can take the space to write your question clearly. You need to carefully explain your question in terms of coordinate time, not proper time, because there simply is no discrepancy to discuss with proper time, like the SI second.

Answer (score 0):

I think the parts about how humans can survive such a state is answered in other answers. I will just address one specific claim that you talked about

> How can this be reconciled with the claim that this duration is
> constant, and not just constant, but so static that it can be used to
> define an SI unit?

The claim is that this duration is constant in **IT's REST FRAME**. It is not constant for all reference frames. For frames moving with some velocity with respect to it, this duration will be different